# Commerce product vatiation attibutes as individual selections

Tags: commerce

I hope this is easy, something I haven't grasped yet learning drupal and commerce.

I have a product, "Vinyl Lettering", and my variations there are three attributes, Height, Width and Rows.
So I have hundreds of variations, such as;
Vinyl lettering-25mm,300mm,1Row
Vinyl lettering-50mm,500mm,2Row
(goes on forever)
The product page only shows one drop-down with the hundreds of variations which looks messy and hard to find the set you want.

To make it easier on the user, I am trying to get the one drop-down to change to the three attributes so that the user can select Height in one drop-down, Within one drop-down and the number of rows in one drop-down,

I am using the latest commerce kickstart with its own Belgrade theme. I am trying to get three drop downs on the product and don't know if it is theme or product, or variation I need to change from the "please select" drop-down.

Anyone that could lead me in the right way would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the attribute system is what you want; these sound to me more like customizations of a product that you're custom producing, no? If so, you likely just need a custom order item type to be used for the base product, with the options for height, width, and rows being fields on the order item itself.